# Stay Hover On Click

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, hover

```css
.radial {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25%;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu a {
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 48px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100em;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  left: 48%;
  margin-left: -24px;
  top: 20px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu a:hover {
  background: #2c3e50;
}
.radial:hover .menu a {
  opacity: 1;
}
.radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0, 170%);
}

.radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-170%, 0%);
}

.radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(170%, 0);
}

/* .radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(0, 200%);
} */

.avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100em;
  color:white;
  background-color:#D63B2F;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.avatar img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;font-size: 15px" >SELECT WIDGET</div>
 <div class='radial' >
    <div class='avatar' style="top: 25px;" >
     <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x" style="top: 7px;left: 10px;position: absolute;"></i>
    </div>
  <div class='menu'>
   
    <a href='#' class="" title='Chart' style="background-color: #E84033" >
      <i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x  radialMenu" ></i>
    </a>
    <a  href='#' class=""  title='Table' style="background-color: #009688" >
      <i class="fa fa-th fa-2x radialMenu " ></i>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class="radialMenu"  title='Map' style="background-color: #3F51B5" >
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x radialMenu" style="left: 20px;" ></i>
    </a>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Here I have Created a Radial Menu, where On Hover Of "+" three Div will Show

I have used HTML and CSS to Hide the div which will only show when i Hover on "+"
Now I want that Hover to be active when i click on "+" and when I click again it should be normal

Please Help me to do it
Its ok If it is done by jquery or by css

Can you please help me to do it

Thanks in Advance.

*[image: Please Check this Screenshot and Also Fiddle Example]*
 [**JS FIDDLE Example**](https://codepen.io/OfficialVikku/pen/YxBWKm)

Comment: When I hover my cursor near by the `+`, then even I get the hover effect. Is it ok for you ?

Comment: No.. I did the Same thing..please check my Snippet.. i need Hover on "+ " and Also when i click on "+" the Hover shud be active until i click it back

Comment: updated fiddle https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJbgdL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".fa-plus").click(function() {

  $(".menu a").eq(0).toggleClass('opacity first-child')
  $(".menu a").eq(1).toggleClass('opacity second-child')
  $(".menu a").eq(2).toggleClass('opacity third-child')

});
```

```css
.radial {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25%;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.menu a {
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 48px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100em;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  left: 48%;
  margin-left: -24px;
  top: 20px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.radial:hover .menu a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(1), .first-child {
  transform: translate(0, 170%);
}

.radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(2), .second-child {
  transform: translate(-170%, 0%);
}

.radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(3), .third-child  {
  transform: translate(170%, 0);
}


/* .radial:hover .menu a:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(0, 200%);
} */

.avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #D63B2F;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.avatar img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;font-size: 15px">SELECT WIDGET</div>
<div class='radial'>
  <div class='avatar' style="top: 25px;">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x" style="top: 7px;left: 10px;position: absolute;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>

    <a href='#' class="" title='Chart' style="background-color: #E84033">
      <i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x  radialMenu"></i>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class="" title='Table' style="background-color: #009688">
      <i class="fa fa-th fa-2x radialMenu "></i>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class="radialMenu" title='Map' style="background-color: #3F51B5">
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x radialMenu" style="left: 20px;"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a specific class and show or hide depending on the class. When shown, change that class so u can hide next time.

For example, put `id="MyElement"` to the `i`. Also add a `class` Yes or No to the `i`

```
    $('.fa-plus').on('click', function () {
      if (document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.contains('Yes') ){
         document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.toggle('No');
         //Apply css as hover effect ones
      }
      else if (document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.contains('No') ){
         document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.toggle('Yes');
      //Apply css to hide
      }
    });
```